# Checking open-source 3rd-party libraries into version control?

Tags: version-control

When using an open-source 3rd-party library in an application being developed for multiple platforms, is it good practice to add the source of all platform variants of the library into version control?

For example, boost contains Unix and Windows downloadable variants.  I would guess it's not a good idea to assume that these packages necessarily contain the same content, and so that each variant should be included?